# Artifact with Lights and Motion Blur

Tags: lighting, artifacts, motion-blur

I came here with this issue because i cant find any sources online that address this, in this clip there is a spaceship, more specifically a tie fighter moving at different speeds throughout the sequence, and the model is parented to the empty (the empty is the one that is animated) the lights are also parented to the empty, and so is the camera, i cannot find a reasonable explanation to why are the lights moving,  so far what i've discovered is that the issue is with motion blur, when the motion blur is disabled the issue is gone,  i have created new scenes and the problem is there (always), i'm posting this to try to understand if what i'm seeing here is accurate, because this is rendered in cycles and lights in "real life" do NOT behave this way. Since the position of the camera to the lights is constant there shouldnt be any motion blur AT ALL.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l4jIvidlHOeqxlpCxUgLo2zBUd56sGIz/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that it's the volumetrics that are causing issue with the motion blur... Is the volumetric a world-based volume or is there an actual mesh that's providing the volume? If it's a mesh then try parenting that to the empty also - so that the volume moves along with the Tie Fighter, instead of the illuminated volume catching the blur.

Comment: i have done exacly what you said but the problem pressists, even without any volume the light still deforms and clips into objects depending on the speeed that is going at

Comment: It's possible this is simply a limitation of how the current implementation of motion blur works or it is a bug. I suppose one workaround (if you only have a single lit object moving through your scene) is to move the scene around the object rather than move the object through the scene - I don't know how hard that would be in your situation. I would suggest creating a cut down minimal example to allow others to easily replicate the problem and raising it as a bug report via menu option Help/Report a Bug in Blender.